# Which types of effect can I put in a presentation using LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, presentations

I used to make my presentation with PowerPoint and Keynote which both were easy but this LaTeX is driving me crazy since you should add anything you want in a hard way!

In fact, I have tried to search about different types of effect I can use for LaTeX presentation but I was not successful to find many.

Is there anyone knows a good source, different effect command, etc.?

Comment: your question is really too vague to answer. In principle you can generate any effect that is supported by pdf. probably the class of choice for presentations these days is beamer, so start with the beamer manual: `texdoc beamer` and then ask if you have any specific questions.

Comment: If this is your first presentation, please do yourself a favour and focus on the content because all the time you spend on playing with the effects will result in a worse presentation. If this is not your first presentation, please do your audience a favour and keep it simple and forget about transition effects.

Comment: @Marc van Dongen this is not my first , I think something like 50th ! however, I am not a guy who add so much effect on a presentation but sometimes it is needed to add one or two ! the problem is that, I cannot find a list of effect which are possible to add in latex like any other presentation software

Comment: It would help if you could add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried and say what effect you want. (Slide transitions, arrows popping up, spinning text, flashing thingumies, jumping up and down equations, strobe lighting...) LaTeX isn't self-contained like most presentation software but a core base with a collection of many independent packages, so there are no complete lists of anything. However, if you say what kind of effect you have in mind, someone might be able to suggest something.

Comment: The easiest effect to add are those of page transitions with `hyeprerref`, supported by Acrobat at least. The other is to use http://impressive.sourceforge.net/ to get additional effects on an existing presentation. From there on the slope is steeper, `beamer` flow commands `\pause` `\visible`, etc. perhaps combined with TikZ, `animate` package, `media9` and so on. The irony is that your presentations will be so much better with beamer that you will not need special effects.

Comment: @Nemo Thanks. Have you read the beamer manual. It contains a section about adding style to your presentations. Also it explains how to add incremental transitions and alerts (highlighting).

Comment: Q: What effects should I put in? A: The fewer, the better. For sure: no crawling ants, and no swirling beams. The less your presentation looks like YAPPP (yet another PowerPoint presentation), the more your audience will appreciate.